# changing the url with modifying the .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help with modifying the url of a website I am working on.

The url is:

```
domainname.com/view-post.php?title=post-title&pid=2
```

I can only get it to say

```
domainname.com/2.html
```

but need it to say

```
domainname.com/posts/post-title
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What method did you use to get your current result of `2.html`? Such issues will require some setting in .htaccess or the apache conf itself, be it mod_rewrite or a 404 handler

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ view-post.php?title=$1&pid=$1

Comment: Are you using a CMS?  like Drupal or Joomla or some such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ view-post.php?title=$1&pid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)/?$  view-post.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That will work if you don't have dash (-). I would recommend to add dashes in both `([a-z0-9\-]+)`, add at the end: `[NC,L,QSA]` and add the `/?` in case someone use the ending `/` eg: `([0-9]+)/?$`

Comment: in addition: ([a-z0-9\-\.]+) -- added dots

Comment: No luck its bringing back a server error, am I missing something out?

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^posts/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)/? $  view-post.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool called "URL Re writer Tool" which you can use to generate htaccess code: try it out here : http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php It's perfect for those who want to Re Write the URLs on their server but don't know what to put in htaccess.